# OG Protocol Breaks when posting a Tumblr Photoset but works when using the Tumblr Facebook App

Tags: facebook, tumblr, facebook-opengraph

When I post a photoset and use the Tumblr intergration to publish to a page it works: http://www.facebook.com/fokus but when I try to post that same page's link to my profile it doesn't show with an image just the description shows.

I tried it in Linter tool and the og:image is not grabbing the photo or photoset. whenever i change the code that is in the {block: Photoset} to anything else (ie Photset-250 or PhotoURL-250} I get this error. I've changed to type from article to webpage and nothing new happens.

> Object at URL
>   'http://blog.fokus.org/post/16945276145/a-soldier-made-of-toy-soldiers'
>   of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '' for property
>   'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

when i inspected the facebook.com/fokus page the image element that shows just one image for the child soliders post is

> https://www.facebook.com/app_full_proxy.php?app=48119224995&v=1&size=z&cksum=5f695f050ed9489725b2a8763c76803c&src=http%3A%2F%2F28.media.tumblr.com%2Ftumblr_lx1z660qCj1qarn5to1_250.jpg